# How to set HSB as the default color space for the color picker on Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Each time I open the color picker on Illustrator I have to change the color space to HSB. Since Illustrator always open with RGB by default, I was wondering whether there is a way to change the default color space option for the color picker.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You can not set the default color mode. It will *always* default back to the Document Color mode (RGB or CMYK). You can set it, but you'll quickly find after clicking a few objects, it'll revert back to the default color mode.

There's no way to permanently set it to a specific color model. This fix has been requested for years.

Comment: Could this be automated somehow with a script?

Comment: @rraallvv No it can not

Answer (score 0):

Switching from RGB to HSL can be recorded as an action and then assigned to a function key.
This does not make it permanent, but spares you clicking through the color picker's options menu every time. Works for me for CS6 on a Mac 10.12.
Kind regards,
Guido